# How to implement multithreading in Spring Batch

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

We have implemented spring batch and which is handling large data set and because of that it is taking too much time to finish it ( around 2 to 4 hours). We have ItemReade, ItemProcesser and ItemWriter.

We are trying to improve performance , code is fine so we are planning to implement multithreading.

Can anybody give suggestion , how to implement multithreading in Spring Batch 
I think we should also take care of member variables which is inject as AutoWired.

Please give your suggestion

Comment: did you already read and tried the options from http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html ?

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used Executor to achieve this , we did following things,

1. Find out the code or portion of the code which took more time to execute.
2. Did analysis that can we use multithreading.
3. Use Executor with our oven framework which make sure that threads are returning in sequence manner how it is inserted.
4. Convert all Member variables to local variables which are having dependency to execute batch as that can cause multithreading problem.
5. We had able to reduce total time from 12 hours to 4 hours of all the spring batch job.

H